# Android Studio: Importing project into existing project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I've got a Eclipse project which I somehow managed to get working in Android Studio awhile back. It uses TouchDB library/project which I now want to upgrade to their latest offering couchbase-lite-android which looks like it comes ready built for Android Studio with gradle files.

However I'm at a loss how to go ahead and import this project into my existing one. File -> Import Project gives me 3 options, create project from existing sources, import from external model (mavern), import from external model (gradle)

If I choose gradle it builds couchdbase-lite-android then opens it into it's own Android Studio window, it definitely doesn't get imported into my current project.

Any ideas...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try going to File -> "Import Module" instead of "Import Project". In Android Studio, an entire window is a project. Each top-level item in that project is called a module. Coming from the Eclipse world, it'd be:

Eclipse workspace = Android Studio project

Eclipse project = Android Studio module

Comment: can the library project be debugged like this?How can it be included?

Answer (score 2):

As for Android Studio ver. 2.1.2 (which I have now) it should be File - New - Import Module... and then choose the path to the project folder to be imported.